# How to customize CSS, specifically enlarge the font size of a specific class

Tags: css, jekyll

How to modify the font size of `.page-heading` class in Jekyll **minima** theme?

I followed [these](https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/) instructions. [This](http://dwmclaughlin.com/) is the website. I am trying to enlarge the font size of page-heading class.

Comment: The reason you are getting so many downvotes is because you have just pasted links which can quickly become outdated or removed and therefore this question will have no benefit to anyone else in future. Please create a minimal and reproducible example of the code that is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using the default Jekyll theme (minima), you need to edit its style sheet.

This theme defines the `.page-heading` class as:

```
.page-heading {
  @include relative-font-size(1.25);
}
```

So it is using a mixin located in `_sass/minima.scss`. Locate the `minima` gem in your gems repository (it will be something like `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-2.1.1/`) and copy that file with its directory to you Jekyll installation:

```
 mkdir -p _sass/
 cp /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-2.1.1/_sass/minima.scss _sass/
```

Now edit `_sass/minima.scss` and change its font size, particularly, you will want to change the `$base-font-size` variable:

```
$base-font-size:   16px !default;

@mixin relative-font-size($ratio) {
  font-size: $base-font-size * $ratio;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll play with it. New to this, obviously. I changed the base-font-size but it changed everything, as I expected, but I just wanted to see if the changes actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Try :

```
.page-heading {
    font-size: 45px !important;
}
```

Comment: Nah didn't work either. Why was I down-voted? Dumb question?

Comment: Are you sure you're adding it in the right stylesheet and that it's not overridden by another stylesheet?

Comment: I created the directories and files it said to, but no I'm not sure.